# How to get all star comments, rate, rate_count with fb graph api

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, comments

I'm using the `Graph API Explorer` to get the 
`star comments`, `star_rating and rating_count`, the url like

```
https://www.facebook.com/weddingdaytaiwan?fields=overall_star_rating,rating_count
```

and get the response

```
{
  "overall_star_rating": 4.9,
  "rating_count": 95,
  "id": "168354659975964"
}
```

I already get the `star_rating` and `rating_count` but what about `star comments`?

Comment: What do you mean by “star comments”? The actual text the user wrote with their review? That you can only get from the specific rating itself - via the `/page-id/ratings` endpoint. (But that is only accessible with a page access token, so you will need admin access to the page.)

Comment: the `star comments` is the comments inside this url (https://www.facebook.com/pg/weddingdaytaiwan/reviews/?ref=page_internal) , and can get review text and star one by one , I don` have page access auth, what I need is to find the target fans page and get the all comments that user have been feedback

Comment: _“and can get review text and star one by one”_ - how, if you don’t have admin access to the page?

Comment: I thought the fans page is public and I also can watch all the comments so guess that have a api can do

Comment: No. Publicly available via UI, and available via API, are two different things. A lot of stuff that you as a user can publicly see via the UI, is not freely accessible via API. As I already said, you will need admin access to the page (or have a page admin grant your app the necessary permissions), otherwise you won’t even get the individual reviews via API.

Comment: Ok, I got it. One more question , How about this web https://www.marry.com.tw/studio-reviews-3061 what tech that they can list the fans page comment? I thought that won’t have permission for every vendor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154348/discussion-between-fan-and-cbroe).